# clicking on drop down menu with href="#nav" using doubletaptogo.js causes page to jump down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a responsive page with a drop down navigation using `doubletaptogo.js`, problem is when I click on the `#nav` link to show the drop down items this causes the page to `scroll down` so the `menu` is now at the `top of the page`.

here is the page: http://goligraphist.com.au/development

I have found that when I `remove all` the content below the `nav` this issue is fixed but this obviously isn't an option. I'm new to `javascript` and this has really got me stuck, any ideas?

**Sample Code** :

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation"> 
   <a href="#nav" title="show menu" class="menu-button">
      <img src="img/menu.png" alt="menu icon">
   </a> 
   <a href="#" title="hide menu" class="menu-button">
     <img src="img/menu.png" alt="menu icon">
   </a> 
   <ul> 
      <li class="active">
         <a href="goligraphist.com.au/development">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
     </li> 
     <li> 
       <a href="#">Contact</a>
     </li> 
   </ul> 
 </nav>
```

**jQuery Script** :

```
<script src="js/doubletaptogo.js"></script> 
<script> 
  $( function() { 
      $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo(); 
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: please share some code with respect to link for which you don't want to make scroll top on click of it.

Comment: <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
          <a href="#nav" title="show menu" class="menu-button"><img src="img/menu.png" alt="menu icon"></a>
          <a href="#" title="hide menu" class="menu-button"><img src="img/menu.png" alt="menu icon"></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="http://goligraphist.com.au/development">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

Comment: the specific link that causes the jump is <a href="#nav" title="show menu" class="menu-button"><img src="img/menu.png" alt="menu icon"></a>

Comment: here is the script I'm using: <script src="js/doubletaptogo.js"></script>
<script>
 $( function()
 {
  $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
 });
</script>

Comment: script is applied to id="nav" and not to href="#nav". I think you can put href="javascript:void(0)" and it should work like expected. just try it once.

Comment: can you elaborate? when I change href="#nav" to href="javascript:void(0)" the dropdown no longer works, do I have to make a change to any other markup on my page?

Comment: I am not much aware of doubletaptogo.js, may be it is using href="#nav" internally. Can you put onclick="return false;" for anchor with href="#nav" like this http://jsfiddle.net/ttpY3/16/

Comment: when I add onclick="return false;" the menu is again not dropping down. Could it be a problem with the doubletaptogo.js code itself?

Comment: I think you need to analyse doubletaptogo.js, that how it is working and then fix the problem.

Comment: as I said I'm new to javascript so that would be tricky for me. here is the js: http://goligraphist.com.au/development/js/doubletaptogo.js

Comment: looking very hard to figure out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally figured this out. Turns out that doubletaptogo.js only works when the nav is at the top of the page and there is no way around this; if the nav is below any other content such as header etc forget about using this script as it will always cause the nav to jump to the top of the page.

I have opted for an alternative drop down that simply uses html and css, no js or jquery needed for this.

See http://goligraphist.com.au/development/ for the update.

That's the end of a major headache.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the following code within DOM ready should stop your page from jumping:

```
$('[href^=\\#]').on('click', function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it stops the drop down from working, is there a special way of using this so the link still works but without the page jump?

Comment: Please provide some minimum drop down markup and how it's supposed to work. Please replace with event.stopPropagation();

Comment: I used this but changed event.stopPropagation() with event.preventDefault() which kept the drop down menus working.

Answer (score 1):

I can see what the issue is here.. You have defined the nav further down the page under the main site image, have you tried moving it right at the top of the page so it defaults to this place?

Also have you tried alternatives - I have achieved this same thing using bootstrap:

```
<nav id="Navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation" >

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="define-spinner">

            </div>
            <a class="homeLogo" href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x icon-color fa-inverse"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="controller">
                <div id="h2Header"><g:message code="default.title" args="[meta(name:'app.name')]"/> </div>

            </li>

         </ul>
         <ul  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >

            <li  class="dropdown controller">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="userMessage">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            <g:message code="default.user.label" default="{{user.username}}" />
                        </span>
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a class="fa fa-gear icon-color" onclick='window.location.href="#/updateusername"' title="${message(code: 'default.username.update', default: 'Update Username')}">
                            <g:message code="default.username.update"  default="Update Username"/>  
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="fa fa-gear icon-color" onclick='window.location.href="#/updatepassword"' title="${message(code: 'default.password.update', default: 'Update password')}">
                            <g:message code="default.password.update"  default="Update Password"/>  
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="controller">
                <a data-ng-controller='UserCtrl' data-ng-click='logout()' title="${message(code: 'security.signoff.label', default: 'Log out')}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> <g:message code="security.signoff.label" default="Sign Off"/>
                </a>
            </li>



        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks Vahid, I'm not a fan of bootstrap so I'll try moving the nav to the top of the page instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `void(0)` for the link like below :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Clickc heere 1</a>
```

or use   `e.preventDefault();`

```
 $('a[href="#"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ttpY3/5/)**

Comment: this doesn't help as I still need href of #nav to be there for the drop down to open

Comment: after viewing source code of link provided by you, i found href="#" in it. Can't you just use href="javascript:void(0)", as anchor click event must be handle by some jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is to write the full URL before the hash (#)

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  $currentPage = 'http' . ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'off' ? 's' : '') . '://';
  $currentPage .= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . htmlentities($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

`<a href="<?php echo $currentPage; ?>#nav" title="show menu" class="menu-button">`

`<a href="<?php echo $currentPage; ?>#" title="hide menu" class="menu-button">`

**Smarty:**

```
<a href="http{if $smarty.server.HTTPS}s{/if}://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST|cat:$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|htmlentities:$smarty.const.ENT_QUOTES}#nav" title="show menu" class="menu-button"> .. </a>

<a href="http{if $smarty.server.HTTPS}s{/if}://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST|cat:$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|htmlentities:$smarty.const.ENT_QUOTES}#" title="hide menu" class="menu-button"> .. </a>
```